# Discord.JS Reaction collector not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const optionsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("What would you like to setup?")
            .setDescription(":one: Prefix\n:two: Mod Log Channel")
            .setColor('RANDOM');
        message.channel.send(optionsEmbed)
            .then(async (msg) => {
                await msg.react('1️⃣');
                await msg.react('2️⃣');

                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣' || reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣' && user.id === message.author.id;
                };

                const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {
                    time: 30000
                });
                let collected = 0;
                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                    collected++;
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === "one") return managePrefix();
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === "two") return manageModLogChannel();
                    msg.delete();
                    collector.end();
                });

                collector.on('end', collected => {
                    if (collected === 0) return message.channel.send("You took too long to react, cancelled setup.");
                });
            });

        async function managePrefix() {
            const getCurrentPrefix = await message.getServerDatabase(message.guild.id, "prefix")
            const currentPrefixEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Info")
                .setDescription("Current Prefix: " + getCurrentPrefix + "\n\nPlease reply with the new prefix or *cancel* to cancel.")
                .setColor('RED');

            message.channel.send(currentPrefixEmbed)
                .then(async (msg) => {
                    const filter = (msgg, user) => {
                        return user.id == message.author.id;
                    }
                    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
                        time: 60000
                    });
                    let collected = 0;
                    collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
                        collected++;
                        msg.delete()

                        if (m.content.toLowerCase() === "cancel") {
                            m.delete();
                            return collector.end()
                        }
                        await message.setServerDatabase(message.guild.id, "prefix", m.content)
                        await m.reply("Set prefix to `" + m.content + "`");

                        collector.end()
                    });

                    collector.on('end', collected => {
                        if (collected === 0) return message.channel.send("You took too long to respond, cancelled setup.")
                    });
                });

        }

        async function manageModLogChannel() {
            const getCurrentPrefix = await message.getServerDatabase(message.guild.id, "modLogChannel")
            const currentPrefixEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Info")
                .setDescription("Current ModLogChannel: <#" + getCurrentPrefix + ">\n\nPlease reply with the new channel or *cancel* to cancel.")
                .setColor('RED');

            message.channel.send(currentPrefixEmbed)
                .then(async (msg) => {
                    const filter = (msgg, user) => {
                        return user.id == message.author.id;
                    }
                    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
                        time: 60000
                    });
                    let collected = 0;
                    collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
                        collected++;
                        msg.delete()

                        if (m.content.toLowerCase() === "cancel") {
                            m.delete();
                            return collector.end()
                        }

                        if (!m.mentions.channels.first()) {
                            m.delete()
                            message.channel.send("Not a valid channel, cancelled setup.");
                            return collector.end();
                        }

                        const channel = m.mentions.channels.first();

                        await message.setServerDatabase(message.guild.id, "modLogChannel", channel.id)
                        await m.reply("Set channel to `<#" + m.content + ">`");

                        collector.end()
                    });

                    collector.on('end', collected => {
                        if (collected === 0) return message.channel.send("You took too long to respond, cancelled setup.")
                    });
                });

        }
```

I am trying to make a config command, upon reacting to the first embed.. nothing happens.
If that first listener is not working, then I doubt the message collectors are working either.
The user should be able to react to a main embed which asks them if they want to change the prefix or mod log channel, from there it will then ask them what they want to change it to with the cancel option, it then saves it in the database using the custom functions (message.getServerDatabase and message.setServerDatabase())
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working as you want it to is that you are calling the `.createReactionCollector()` method on the wrong `Message` object. You should create the reaction collector on `msg` instead of `message`.

Like this:

```js
const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
    time: 30000
});
```

Also `collector.end()` is not a function, you probably want to use `collector.stop()` instead.